# Return empty string in c

Tags: c, string

In my function I want to return an empty string `""`, function looks like this:

```
char *myFunction(nodeType *arg){
   if (something){
      return anotherFunction(arg);
   } else {
      return EMPTYSTRING;
   }
}
```

(EMPTYSTRING should be replaced with correct expression to return `""`)

> Some ways I came up with:

```
return ""

return '\0'
```

---

**What is the right way to return an empty string?**

Comment: '\0' is not correct. That's not a char *. You're returning null, not an empty string.

Comment: So is the "" same type as char* ?

Comment: I would've `return`ed `NULL` in place of `EMPTYSTRING`

Comment: I can't return NULL, because later I concatenate returned values, so it will be worse implementation, if I have to check every returned values for NULL

Comment: If you don't return null, you're going to have to malloc every time you return an empty string because you're returning `char *` and not `const char *`. Just something to be aware of. `return ""` will give you read-only memory that shouldn't be freed.

Comment: static const "" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not good idea to return "". Because, it is const char and you may try to dealloc it in where you get it from the function and this likely crashes your application.

So, I would return `strdup("")`, so you can free it safely.

Comment: I would not assume anotherFunction allocated memory without seeing a code

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky I assumed that `anotherFunction` allocates memory because the return type is `char *` and not `const char *`. Though I concede it's entirely possible they're just using the wrong return type. @OP, make sure to free the string returned from `strdup`.

Answer (score 3):

`return '\0'` is not correct; it is a null character.

```
return "";
```

is more correct.

And you can make a small test function to test returning an empty string, before your data structure is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

`\0` is indeed *a* null-pointer constant, not an empty string, so returning that would still return a null pointer.

However you've got *another* problem here.

If `anotherFunction` returns a string that you don't need to `free()` then it is correct to return `""` here. If it returns a dynamically `malloc()`ated string that you must `free()`, then you also need to return a dynamically allocated empty string here - `return calloc(1, 1);` would do the trick.